# Which algorithm should I use to match the pattern or finding intersection between datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, cluster-analysis, minhash

I have personID and VaccinationsID plotted in x and y axis. 
I want to group those personIDs who have the most **similar selection** of vaccinations. I am trying to use clustering machine learning algorithm. But I am not sure whether I should use this algorithm or user collaborative filtering.

My aim is to achieve Jaccard indexing, that is finding the intersection or similarities between 10000s of persons and form clusters and label them. Based on the degree of similarities, I need to group the personsID. Could anyone tell me which is an efficient approach? also if it is feasible to do using clustering for millions of data

[image]

I have added the screenshot of the graph

Answer (score 0):

Number of vaccinations is an integer.

Just partition your data by this value, no need for clustering.

Everybody that has 7 vaccination goes into list 7.

Comment: It is the vaccinationID. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.  I need to group persons having same vaccinationIDs. So, like the below sets, p1 = {2,4,5,6 } , p2 = {2,4,7,8,9}, p3 = {7,10,13,34}. Now, p1 and p2 are more similar when compared with p2 and p3. And I have to do this for millions of people.

Comment: I am planning to use user collaborative approach here. But, my values are not a rating like in the movie recommendation system. It is the selection of those vaccine type. So, I am a bit confused as to how I can find the similarity and cluster them or rank the most similar users.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of analysis, I used K-modes clustering algorithm. Based on the dissimilarity, the clusters are formed. Below is the link to the video of how the K-modes algorithm work. 
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b39_vipRkUo]